# What the sequence of UITable view Datasource and delegate when we reload data from table?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hello I'm beginner in iOS In one of my activity I want to reload table data ...then I have applied this code .....

```
 -(void)buttonpress
{

   for(int i=0;i<buttonarr.count;i++)
   {
       NSString *butt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[buttonarr objectAtIndex:i]];

       for(int j=0;j<LabelTag.count;j++)
       {
            NSString *labelbutt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[LabelTag objectAtIndex:j]];

            if([butt isEqualToString:labelbutt])
            {
                  NSIndexPath *indexPath1 =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0];
                        NSLog(@"indexPath %@",indexPath1);
                        UITableViewCell *mycel=[self->table_AdviseTestDetails cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1];
                        NSLog(@"cell %@",mycel);

                        UILabel *mybutton=(UILabel*)[mycel viewWithTag:100+j];
                        // mybutton.selected=YES;
                        NSLog(@"label %@",mybutton.text);


                        r=r+[mybutton.text floatValue];
                        NSLog(@"r %f",r);


                    }

                }
            }

          range=1;
```

> [table_AdviseTestDetails reloadData];

```
        netcharges.text=0;
            z1=0;

            NSLog(@"label arr %@",LabelArr);


                   for(int i=0;i<LabelArr.count;i++)
                    {
                        NSString *y= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[LabelArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"value"]];


                     z1=z1+[y integerValue];


                        netcharges.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",z1];
                        NSLog(@"net %@",netcharges.text);
                        //balance.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",z];

                    }
                    netcharges.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[netcharges.text floatValue]-r];

                    NSLog(@"net %@",netcharges.text);
                    point.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",(floor([netcharges.text integerValue]/[[[Point_Result objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Value"] integerValue]))*[[[Point_Result objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Points"] integerValue]];
                    balance.text=netcharges.text;
                    NSLog(@"net %@",balance.text);


        }
```

This is my code please ignore all code think is there [table_AdviseTestDetails reloadData];
when we reload table then my controller go in table datasource ...
         - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 and after this controller come below line of  this 
          [table_AdviseTestDetails reloadData]; 
and after this controller goes in ...
         - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
I have problem there .....I want when we reload table then first all datasource and delegate  of UITableview run  and then run other thing.....
 So IN my above code ....I want fist reload table data use this

```
    [table_AdviseTestDetails reloadData];
```

then run all delegate and datasource of table.....

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and controller  come after this below of    [table_AdviseTestDetails reloadData];
this line .....how can do this ..please solve this problem ......thank in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

these is the general sequence i am not including all the methods just required ones are here

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Table view data source
1) -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
2) -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
3) -(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
4) -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
1) -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I know this but In above of my code where I wrote line   [table_AdviseTestDetails reloadData]; I want to run all these delegate and datasource sequently but ......not here .....use this line [table_AdviseTestDetails reloadData]; my controller go in  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  and after this is not go in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath instead of this controller go back in my code then go -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: so is that creating any issue?

Comment: yes ,I want first run all delegate and datasource of table but this is not

Comment: delegates are user interaction based events so that will not going to be called automatically but don't know your cellForRowAtIndexpath method is why not calling it should though.